# $G$-invariant bilinear maps

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $M$ a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. Then $M \otimes k$ is a representation of $G$ for any field $k$. I am interested in the number of ways we can turn $M \otimes k$ into a (non associative) $kG$-algebra. Equivalently, I would like to compute $\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M\otimes M \otimes k, M \otimes k)$.

Suppose that we know that $M\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is irreducible and that $M \otimes M \otimes \mathbb{C}$ contains a unique composition factor isomorphic to $M \otimes \mathbb{C}$. Then we know, by Schur's lemma, that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(M\otimes M \otimes \mathbb{C}, M \otimes \mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}$. What can we say about $\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M\otimes M \otimes k, M \otimes k)$?

I have the feeling that $\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M\otimes M \otimes k, M \otimes k) \cong k$ if $k$ is algebraically closed and $\operatorname{char}(k) \nmid \left| G \right|$. Is this correct and if so, why? In the other cases, I think that a good knowledge of modular representation theory might give a sufficient answer but I am not sure where I should start looking in the literature.

Comment: Is it correct that $M \otimes k$ means $M \otimes_{\mathbb Z} k$, but $M \otimes M \otimes k$ means $M \otimes_{\mathbb ZG} M \otimes_{\mathbb Z} k$?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, that is correct. By $M \otimes M \otimes k$, I really mean the tensor product of the representation $M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} k$ with itself. It could also have written $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G} M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G} kG$.

Comment: Do you want to assume $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-free? Otherwise it could have a large summand annihilated by $\text{char}(k)$ and $M\otimes k$ would have little to do with $M\otimes\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I am not really sure. Probably, if that is the only way that I can say something useful. How can we check whether $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-free? Or can you always find a $\mathbb{Z}$-free $N$ such that $N \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong M \otimes \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @MichielVanCouwenberghe, you can take $N$ to be the quotient of $M$ by its torsion submodule.

Comment: @JeremyRickard To be more precise, I am especially interested in the case where $M$ is the zero weight space of a Weyl module $V(\lambda)$ of a linear algebraic group over $\mathbb{Z}$, considered as a module for the Weyl group. Do you know whether this is $\mathbb{Z}$-free?

Comment: @JeremyRickard I think I just answered my own question. Since the Weyl module itself is $\mathbb{Z}$-free, the same is true for the zeto weight space since it is a submodule of a free module over a PID. So yes, I think that I want to assume that $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-free.